# Git update/replace folder and contents

Tags: git

I have a folder with files and sub folder in it and I have created a branch where I have been editing this folder and actually committed this (but not yet merged with the master).

However, I think I might have an issue if I do merge.

Assume my folder structure was like this:

```
Folder 
  - Sub-Folder A 
    - File A1
    - File A2
    - File A3
  - Sub-Folder B
    - File B1
    - File B2
    - File B3
```

And now I have edited to become:

```
Folder 
  - Sub-Folder A 
    - File A2 (Edited)
    - File A3
    - File A4
  - Sub-Folder C
    - File C1
    - File C2
    - File C3
```

I.E., File A1 deleted, File A2 edited, new File A4, Sub-Folder B and all contents deleted, a new Sub-Folder C.

I am concerned that the commit just seemed to have added the new and edited stuff and that the removed/deleted stuff will still be there when I merge.

Is this the case? How can I resolve if so?

I was thinking I should create a temp branch from master, git rm -f the folder, merge this back into master to remove the folder and then merge in the branch with the edits.

Is this a valid/workable approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell git about the files that you have removed. If you do a git status, it should list: A/A1, B/B1, B/B2, B/B3 as having been deleted. Having re-created your situation locally and then removed the files, git status gives:

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   A/A4
#   new file:   C/C1
#   new file:   C/C2
#   new file:   C/C3
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    A/A1
#   deleted:    B/B1
#   deleted:    B/B2
#   deleted:    B/B3
```

If you do 'git rm' on each of A/A1, B/B1, B/B2 and B/B3 (despite the fact that the files no longer exists on disk) and commit those changes then it should all be fine.

Does that help? Let me know if I need to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

your work/change branch from your master is a reference. If you delete, change , rename in your working branch and commit anything. Git will merge everything in a proper way. But is important your working and master branch shout be me clean.

for a clean up you need only "git add ." and "git commit". It is not necessary to use "git rm" for a proper merge.

the git status shout like this, in this example I'm working in my remove branch):

```
git status
# On branch remove
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

now you can switch to the master branch:

```
git checkout master
```

check if master is clean:

```
git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

now is the time to merge in your master branch

```
git merge remove
Updating 7989dd1..d28cdee
Fast-forward
 {B => A}/demo2 |    0
 1 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename {B => A}/demo2 (100%)
```

git status shout have the same output (before merge)

```
git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

you can kick the old branch, if you want with:

```
git branch -d remove
Deleted branch remove (was d28cdee).
```